# EDIT column value on spark dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a dataframe :

```
+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|Distance            | KM              | KM_previous        |
+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|0                   | 0.0             |50                  |
|0                   |0.0              |0.0                 |
+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

I want to edit the value of `Distance` according to a condition, So I'm using the followinf code :

```
  dataframee.withColumn("Distance",when(col("KM").notEqual(0.0).or(col("KM_previous ").notEqual(0.0)),abs(col("KM").minus(col("KM_previous ")))));
```

But I get a new column with null values.

How can I edit the Distance column without having a new column ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a simple typo, `col("KM_previous ") -> col("KM_previous")`. Even though, you did not set the `.otherwise`, so the second row will have the `null` value.

```
dataframee.withColumn("Distance",
    when(col("KM").notEqual(0.0).or(col("KM_previous").notEqual(0.0)),
         abs(col("KM").minus(col("KM_previous")))
    )
);
```